# LDAP authentication inh php

Tags: php, authentication, ldap, phpldapadmin

I am trying to create a login page in php using LDAP authentication. For this I've installed phpldapadmin on a linux machine(Virtual machine). I am using WAMP on another machine to develop the loging page, but dont know where to start. Also When I try to enable the authnz_ldap module in wamp the services wont restart.

Kindly Advise, on how can I proceed and please excuse me as I have as good as no idea on how to proceed with this.

Thanks in advance
Ravi

Comment: pls post the error log (the reason why apache don't start) here ...

Comment: [Fri Aug 01 12:41:19.100372 2014] [authnz_ldap:error] [pid 4208:tid 440] AH01749: Module mod_ldap missing. Mod_ldap (aka. util_ldap) must be loaded in order for mod_authnz_ldap to function properly
AH00016: Configuration Failed

Comment: => install mod_ldap and enable it :D